# Fixing an authentication error with the GEE plugin

Tags: google-earth-engine, qgis-plugins, authentication

I'm having trouble with the GEE plugin, I have followed lots of suggestions about fixing the authentication error but unfortunately they didn't work. So what can I do? I share here the error displayed in the Python QGIS when I run the authentication

```
import ee
Starting Google Earth Engine Authorization ...
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2023 11:30:50] "GET /?code=4/0AZEOvhWBhvXenbZJmf8nCxdY0NOEFokBiqt_qdpvhyR6Hqz45w_WaqZdp5feFfFN3pL8ew&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/earthengine%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth HTTP/1.1" 200 -
QGIS EE Plugin authenticated successfully

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 326, in _execute_cloud_call
    return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/algorithms?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access". Details: "Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/vizca/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\__init__.py", line 42, in __wrapping_ee_import__
    _module_.Initialize(http_transport=httplib2.Http())
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\__init__.py", line 140, in Initialize
    ApiFunction.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\apifunction.py", line 154, in initialize
    signatures = data.getAlgorithms()
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 1128, in getAlgorithms
    return _cloud_api_utils.convert_algorithms(_execute_cloud_call(call))
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 328, in _execute_cloud_call
    raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 326, in _execute_cloud_call
    return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/algorithms?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access". Details: "Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.7\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users/vizca/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\ee_plugin\__init__.py", line 46, in __wrapping_ee_import__
    _module_.Initialize(http_transport=httplib2.Http())
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\__init__.py", line 140, in Initialize
    ApiFunction.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\apifunction.py", line 154, in initialize
    signatures = data.getAlgorithms()
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 1128, in getAlgorithms
    return _cloud_api_utils.convert_algorithms(_execute_cloud_call(call))
  File "C:\Users\vizca\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\ee_plugin\extlibs_windows\ee\data.py", line 328, in _execute_cloud_call
    raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Not signed up for Earth Engine or project is not registered. Visit https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/access
```